# How to call a function from another class in python

Tags: python, class

```
class A:
  def add_f(self,a,b):
    return a+b

class B:
  def sum_f(self,a,b,c):
    return A.add_f(a,b) + c

B1= B()    
print B1.sum_f(1,2,3)


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/wxu/Documents/test.py", line 10, in <module>
print B1.sum_f(1,2,3)
File "C:/Users/wxu/Documents/test.py", line 7, in sum_f
return A.add_f(a,b) + c
TypeError: unbound method add_f() must be called with A instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

When I don't have the self for sum_f(self,a,b,c), it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/wxu/Documents/test.py", line 10, in <module>
print test1.sum_f(1,2,3)
TypeError: sum_f() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Why is that?
And how to call function add_f from class A in class B? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're not asking the right queston here - this code errors before it even tries to call `A.add_f`

Comment: Ok. So how do I get rid of the error first please? Thank you

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391828/how-to-call-a-class-method-in-another-method-in-python?rq=1

Comment: Why make `add_f` an instance method if you need to call it without an instance of `A`? Why make it part of a class at all? With the very little information we have, it seems like a better candidate for a module method.

Comment: Hey @Catherine I updated my answer. You missed a small detail in it before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a few things.

1. When you define class methods, they **must** have `self` as the first parameter.
2. The part where you had an error is where you tried to call B as a variable. B is a class, and you must call it like any other class. This also applies when you are calling `A()` in class B.

Revised code:

```
class A:
    def add_f(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class B:
    def sum_f(self, a, b, c):
        return A().add_f(a, b) + c

print B().sum_f(1, 2, 3)
```

Update:
Thanks for taking my advice but you're still missing something. In class B you call a method from class A, but you need parentheses for that too! In class B, call class A as such:

`A().add_f(a, b)`

Comment: labeling the first parameter `self` is convention, not a requirement.

Comment: She already creates the variable B1 with which she is using to access the object; she doesn't need to make another.

Comment: I see the asker edited the question using only part of my answer. I'll reflect that and update mine as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, ProfOak! It's working now. And you explained it very well!

Answer (score 0):

Simple fixes, you just need to open and close the brackets on your class declarations, so `class B` becomes `class B()` (Same thing applied to class A). Also, you need to add some kind of variable such as self as the first argument of each method declared within a class. You never need to pass anything as this first argument to fill self, as python will do it for you.

As for your A.add_f issue, you just need to do as you did with B, and instantiate it an A object to something like A1, and then call the method of A1.